# Cannot set the background colour of image view when it don't have an image resource

Tags: android, android-imageview, setbackground

I want set a background colour to an ImageView, when the imageview has an image resource, it works and i get my background colour but when the image view don't have an image resource, SetBackgroundColor don't work and do nothing, this is my code :

xml Layout :

```
       <ImageView android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/favor_item_image" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

java code :

```
       ImageView favorImage = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.favor_item_image);  
       //favorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.btndelete);
       favorImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255,0,0));
```

So, when i comment this line : //favorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.btndelete); i cannot set the image view background colour ,  but when i uncomment this line, setBackgroundColor works fine.

any help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing anything is because you have the layout_height set to wrap_content. When you do not have an image set on the ImageView wrap_content sets the height to 0. If you want the color to display without an image you will have to set the layout_height to an actual value such as 50dp.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView` has a height of `wrap_content`, and when you only set the background color, it has no content. Therefore doesn't show up. You should be able to fix this by setting a different height.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting: `android:adjustViewBounds=false` I may be mistaken but when this is set to `true` the view might scale to 0 width and 0 height when it doesn't have an image.